# Get all values between delimiters in large string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string that has bunch of text. I need to locate all values that are located between
'site.com/PI/' and '/500/item.jpg

Example:

```
String STRING = @"
http://site.com/PI/0/500/item.jpg
blah-blah
http://site.com/PI/1/500/item.jpg
blah-blah
http://site.com/PI/2/500/item.jpg
blah-blah
http://site.com/PI/4/500/item.jpg
blah-blah
http://site.com/PI/8/500/item.jpg
blah-blah
http://site.com/PI/6/500/item.jpg    blah-blah"
```

need to get list of { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 6 }

It is easy to get one occurence using regex:

```
Regex.Match(STRING, @"(?<=/PI/).*(?=/500/)").Value;
```

How can I get all occurencies into one list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ.

```
List<string> matches = Regex.Matches(STRING, @"(?<=/PI/).*(?=/500/)")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(m => m.Value)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: I( have never done it before- when I use your example, my syntax is red-highlighted

Comment: That doesn't compile. MatchCollection does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Instead, `Regex.Matches(bla,bla).Cast<Match>().Select...`

Comment: `OfType` is unnecessary, because all items in the `MatchCollection` are guaranteed to be of type `Match`. It's wasteful to test if they are. Thus, `.Cast<Match>` is more appropriate.

Comment: @spender: Is a simple test really worse than a cast?

Comment: "The OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in source that can be cast to type TResult". There's no need to filter... they're all `Match` instances.

Comment: I looked at it in Reflector. `OfType<>` uses `obj is TResult`, `Cast<>` uses `(TResult)obj`. I'm guessing the `is` version is faster.

Comment: Huh? How can a test followed by a cast (OfType implementation) be faster than a cast without a test (Cast implementation)? Besides. my issue is with correctness of code, not optimization. The intended use of OfType is when you have an IEnumerable of mixed types, to extract items that only match that type. Cast makes the assumption that the IEnumerable contains only items of a single type. This is satisfied by MatchCollection... it's an IEnumerable containing only Match instances.

Comment: I missed the cast in the Reflector code. (Horribly complicated stuff.) You were right. It does use a cast, and the test is of course overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Matches` function for that. It will return a collection of `Match` objects.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(STRING, @"(?<=/PI/).*(?=/500/)")
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
  Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```